# Advice on custom lists in Sharepoint 2016 - 5K item limits etc

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

hope you doing all good.
I am here to seek for advice and your experience / expertise.

Is it plausible to create multiple forms within 1 single custom list in SharePoint 2016 even after knowing the limits of 5.000 items ?!

Once you enable "Allow management of content types" you can then create different content type by utilizing the same columns etc.

My worry is that someday that single custom list will collapse due to the items amount (which at the moment is about 200) but imagine having 5 content types and they be running for years.

I am just lost and not sure how to tackle this. Yes, I can always create a list for each form but I thought maybe having all in one list is easy manageable because the columns will be reused among other content types.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid of using multiple Document Libraries or Lists - as long as users can find them they will learn how to use multiple places.  If your List content types are split between multiple lists it will still be fine, it is very good that your are planning ahead to 'future proof' what you are setting up.

Just make sure you use a navigation bar (the one that runs along the top of the screen).

Navigation links: [readme1](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-navigation-best-practices/), [readme2](https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-create-drop-navigation-sharepoint/), [readme3](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-inherit-navigation-in-sharepoint/).

Let's imagine you have 1000s of the same item content type, you can also create multiple Lists to handle this.  As long as you modify the navigation, so users can find everything, it does not matter is multiple Lists are being used.  Here is a screen shot where something similar was done in my Sharepoint, it uses lots of Document Libraries but the principle is the same - splitting up the same item/content type across multiple 'locations' (Lists or Document Libraries).  In this picture you see the navigation has been customised and the background shows 'all site contents' - there are loads of Document Libraries grouping projects.  Each EXP is a project, but the file size in them is too much to allow them to all be saved in the same place.  So, they have been split up!

[image: Navigation customised and site contents screen shot]

You may wish to **Save your existing custom List as a Template** - go in List Settings>Save List As Template>you can also choose to copy all existing Content as part of the template.  Then when you create a new List, for example, it can have all the existing items - then you could delete out all the content types you don't want in the new List.  Then remove the content types you don't want in the new list, so that when people do 'create new item' they have only 1 content type to choose from.

Some additional things you may wish to consider:

Configuring Document Libraries: [Readme](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-document-library-one-many/)

Depending on the size of your organisation, you may wish to create more than one site collection.  For instance Finance and Human Resources should be split off in to separate site collections so that the security can be better managed.  You might need additional departmental site collections, though if your organisation is small perhaps there is no need to.

Site collection limits for Sharepoint Online (not sure if SP 2016 = SP Online?): [readme](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498)

'How to overcome the 5000 item limit' (could be interesting for you too): [readme](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/)

Comment: Hey Tally, cheers for the feedback. I will be using the custom list instead of the document library.  The custom list can be used to create forms via Nintex etc. and my worry was using one single custom list for like 5 content types (imagine each of content type having thousands of items) meaning its goes over 5k items or beyond.  Indeed, the finance , HR, Purchasing etc have got their own page on sharepoint and now working on the Finance bit where they want a lot of paper form be implemented into Sharepoint ...

Comment: I've added a picture and explanation about how to handle 1000s of items.

Comment: I've updated answer to explain how to save your existing List as a Template.

Comment: ah, I just saw the image. Yes, that is a possibility to create a custom list for each form, and that is what I been doing so far BUT my thoughts were to combine all Finance form into one custom list :) - i was fine with it until I read about the 5K limitation. This made me worry about and think whether that is worth doing ...

Comment: by the way, I will NOT be using folders but rather the metadata and this probably wont have an effect on the 5k issue. At least this is what I understood from the link article you provided.

Comment: Hmmm, are you thinking of combining all forms in to one 'super-form' or simply thinking about saving all the Finance forms in a single custom list?  I reread your question and I realise I did not answer your question on Columns.  [This post](https://sharepointmaven.com/shall-create-list-column-site-column/) looks at Column creation at List or Site Collection Level.   At my work most columns are made at the List level, whereas in my old job all columns were created at the Site Collection level and, if needed, were manually added to a new List.  How is your Sharepoint deployed in this respect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70097/discussion-between-tally-and-bucki).

Comment: Hi Bucki: we could use the chat instead.  Just click here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70097/discussion-between-tally-and-bucki

Comment: sorry, missed ur chat invitation .... i am on it now, if ur available.